# How to get list attribute/field WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How do I get a list of claim attributes, because when an update uses CURL, the last name is "familyname" while in the list http://wso2.org/claims is "lastname".
This can confuse me when I want to update user attributes via CURL.
can anyone share the CRUD attribute fields via CURL

Comment: There is actually an error in the mapping. so do following changes
In the management console, go to Home > Identity > Claims > List > claim.view Click on http://wso2.org/oidc/claim in the Available Claims Dialect list

Comment: You seem to be using SCIM 2 for crud operations. And to list user attributes what method you are using?